# Bind with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, bind

How can I call native bind method of function-object with coffeescript ? This is the example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(e){
    this._filter(true);
    }.bind(this);
 )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add some parentheses around the function so that you can `.bind` the right thing:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ((e) ->
    this._filter(true)
).bind(this))
```

That will use the native `bind` method instead of the usual `var _this = this` trickery that CoffeeScript's `=>` uses.